# Convert AsymmetricKeyParameter to der format key

Tags: c#, rsa

I am using the [Bouncycastle C# crypto library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) and I want to convert an AsymmetricKeyParameter object that represents a *public* key to DER format. I know how to do this with an AsymmetricKeyParameter object that represents a *private* key but I can't figure out do it for a public key.

Here is my code:

```
PrivateKeyInfo infoPrivate = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(asymeterickey);
byte[] serializedPrivateKey = infoPrivate.PrivateKey.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded();
string derPrivateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(serializedPrivateKey);
```

Comment: is it strange?  , Convert AsymmetricKeyParameter to der format key with castle in c#?

Comment: I'm going to liberally edit this question to make it closer to understandable. Normally I wouldn't edit this much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the class you are looking for is `Org.BouncyCastle.X509.SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory`

Answer (score 0):

thanks friend 
I found that!

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;

SubjectPublicKeyInfo publicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(asymetericKey);
```